# Convert DMS to Decimal Degress

Tags: r-sp

trying to convert this `110°15"27.81' W` lat data to decimal degrees using `char2dms`.
keep getting this error

> Error in if (any(abs(object@deg) > 360)) return("abs(degree) > 360") else if (any(object@WS &  : 
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

any ideas

Comment: An idea is that a conversion is not successful and a `NULL` is returned. Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: You have to reformat a bit the string so that char2dms recognizes it correctly. `as.numeric(char2dms("110°15'27.81\"W", chd = "°" ))` should work (note that I switched the minutes and seconds separators in the input string)